# Setting Default Label options in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, labeling

In ArcMap 10.3 I am looking to set the default style for my labels as white with a black halo for any newly added or created layer. Is this possible? I am getting tired of altering each one as they are brought in or created. I have worked with the "labeling" tool but still have to change any incoming layer to the halo style I need.

Comment: are you looking for this? Import Labels from Another Layer http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dbb7be9d2c1c491e8c1a067ffd58aea8

Comment: Unfortunately no. Each layer I create will have a their own attributes associated. I just want the style to be defaulted to 'halo'. Everything I have seen shows how to change the default size, font or otherwise, but nothing on styles or colors. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set a default for new layers, but you can save styles and use them again later on other layers.

Open the Symbol Selector dialog ([see help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-changing-the-appearance-of-label.htm)), click Save As, and give your style a name and optionally, some tags. Then you can select this style on your new layer.

[image]